# UIDocument autosave not working when calling updateChangeCount

Tags: ios, uikit, uidocument

I have a custom subclass of `UIDocument` that I use to store the user's content for my app. I call `-[UIDocument updateChangeCount:UIDocumentChangeDone]` directly to track changes to the document. Saving and loading work fine, but the document never autosaves. Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was that I wasn't calling `-[UIDocument updateChangeCount:]` from the main thread. Despite the fact that UIDocument isn't a UI element, it is still part of `UIKit` and so the usual caveats about always interacting with `UIKit` classes from the main thread still applies.

Wrapping the code in a dispatch to the main queue fixed the issue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [doc updateChangeCount:UIDocumentChangeDone];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First, an update on Jayson's answer for Swift:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    doc.updateChangeCount(.done)
}
```

This works fine if you are just calling it in one or two places. However, if you have multiple calls, and a possibility of them being on background threads, then it may be beneficial to sub class `UIDocument` and override the `updateChangeCount(:)` function so that you enforce a main call. Otherwise, you become responsible for making the main call every time, which opens you up to a potential miss, leading to the document getting into the `saveError` state.

You would then have an override in your subclass like this:

```
override func updateChangeCount(_ change: UIDocumentChangeKind) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        super.updateChangeCount(change)
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually did something similar, although I added my own method `addChange(_:)` that updates my own change flags and calls `updateChangeCount(_:)` on the main thread. In my case I do want to be able to call `updateChangeCount` synchronously when I know I’m already on the main thread, so the override wouldn’t work.